# How To Change the "div" Color based on Background?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, frontend

I have a black chatbot icon on the bottom right of the website. My web footer has a black background as well.  So I need to change the color of the Chatbot to white as I scroll to the bottom of the page.

I used Scroll bar Height to make the color difference.

Comment: Hi there, for the moment, your question is rather unclear. I suggest you share appropriate code snippets, and perhaps show what you have tried and where that has failed to produce the desired result. As it stands, I don't think you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean that you want a fixed icon to have a white color when the background is black and black if the background color is white while scrolling?

if u mean that then use on that fixed element this code in CSS `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

and sorry if i miss understood the question i think its better to add some code to
explain what u want better